# Why can't an internal event in a class implement an event on an internal interface?

Tags: c#

I have an internal interface which defines some events and a sample class which implements the interface:

```
internal interface IMyEvents
{
    event EventHandler MyEvent;
}

public class MyClass : IMyEvents
{
    internal event EventHandler MyEvent;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        if (MyEvent != null) MyEvent(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error CS0737: 'MyClass' does not implement interface member '.IMyEvents.MyEvent'. 'MyClass.MyEvent' cannot implement an interface member because it is not public.
```

What's going on here?  It's an internal interface, so I don't see why the event has to be public.

Comment: the way you're invoking `MyEvent` is not thread-safe. You should either create a defensive copy, or initialize your event to `delegate { }`, which has the added benefit that you don't have to worry about `null` anymore.

Comment: @svick: Do we have any evidence whatsoever that the program is multithreaded? Making a not-multithreaded program threadsafe is a waste of valuable time.

Comment: @Eric, AFAIK, we don't. Generally, I agree with you, but when the fix is as simple as this, I think it's worth doing it. Especially since the `delegate { }` solution makes the calling code simpler.

Comment: Go ahead and edit it if you like.  If it's really that simple to make it threadsafe, then I welcome the improvement!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly implement `IMyEvents`.

```
public class MyClass : IMyEvents
{
    // ...

    event EventHandler IMyEvents.MyEvent
    {
        add { MyEvent += value; }
        remove { MyEvent -= value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Members that implement an interface are required to be either **public** or **explicit** in C#, regardless of the accessibility of the interface.

This is a "simplifying" rule; if you do otherwise then you get into the quagmire that is C++ accessibility, where there is public inheritance, private inheritance, and so on. We'd rather keep it simple: if you want to implement an interface, either **make a public member**, or **say explicitly that you are implementing the interface**.

Answer (score 1):

C# doesn't allow that because it insists that either the implementing member is public or that it's an explicit implementation (in which case it will end up being private, but you can still access it through a reference to the interface). You can do that in VB.NET though.